# A Question Regarding Second-Order ZFC

Tags: set-theory

How is the Axiom 'V=L' related to Second-Order ZFC?  Since it is consistent relative to first-order ZFC, is it consistent relative to second-order ZFC as well?  Since 'V=L' is a first-order axiom, is there a second-order analogue to 'V=L' one must consider in order to make the question "Is [V=L] consistent relative to second-order ZFC" sensible?

Comment: Usually when people say "second-order ZFC", they mean second-order ZFC with standard semantics, which is a non-recursive theory (because second-order logic with standard semantics doesn't have a recursive proof system).  Is that what you're talking about?  If so, then the answer is quite interesting: if the continuum hypothesis (or V = L) is true, then it "follows" from second-order ZFC, whereas if it's false, then it's negation "follows".  (I'm using "follows" in a semantic sense).  But there's not really a way to tell which of these is true.  See here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/78083

Comment: By the way, as mentioned in that Math.Overflow answer, you don't even need to go to a theory as powerful as second-order ZFC to have this phenomenon.  The continuum hypothesis can be written as a statement of third-order arithmetic, and if it's true, then it "follows" from third-order arithmetic (with standard semantics), and if it's false, then its negation "follows".

Comment: @ keshav: yes, that is exactly what I am talking about.  The motivation for asking the question is to see whether the following theorem of Paul Cohen applies in the second-order case (found on pages 108-9 of his book SET THEORY AND THE CONTINUUM HYPOTHESIS, Dover Edition):  "From ZF+SM or indeed from any axiom system containing ZF which is consistent with V=L, one cannot prove the existence of an uncountable standard model in which AC is true and CH false, nor even one in which AC holds and which contains non-constructible real numbers."  Although Cohen certainly intended the theorem

Comment: to apply to the first-order case, if one studies the proof (found on page 109), there seems nothing in that proof limiting it to apply only to the first-order case.  If that is the case then (since second-order ZFC is Categorical and thus essentially has only one uncountable model) if (as in the first-order case) second-order ZFC has L as its smallest inner model (since by the fact that second-order ZFC is categorical and therefore can be deemed to contain 'all' the ordinals), one has, by Cohen's proof, a 'ready-made' continuum, that is, the continuum of the constructible reals.

Comment: In fact, by the categoricity of second-order ZFC, L (whatever form of it is the correct form for second-order ZFC) would seem to be THE model for second-order ZFC (and L could again be deemed to be "the rewarder of the patient").

Comment: @ThomasBenjmain Second-order ZFC is not actually categorical.  It can be made categorical, however, if you add axioms concerning exactly what inaccessible cardinals exist.  See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/317763/71829

Comment: @keshav:  Very interesting.  It would seem, then, that for the first inaccessible cardinal k, V_k=L could hold, or am I misunderstanding Asaf's answer?